# r subset matrix by index and row name

Tags: r, matrix

Is it possible to subset a matrix by both index and row name in the same call? I've been able to do it separately but when I try to do it at the same time I get a "subscript out of bounds" error.

For example:

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(20), nrow = 5, ncol = 4)
rownames(x) <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
```

I know I can subset rows 1:3 by doing x[1:3,] or by doing x[c("a", "b", "c"),]

But is is possible to get rows 1:3 and then 5 by doing a call for the rows by number and row name? I've tried to do

```
x[c(1:3, "e"),]
```

But get the error mentioned above. Obviously for a small matrix like this I know I could just do c(1:3,5) but I'm working with a larger matrix where I want to use the top set of rows in addition to 1 or 2 other rows from further down in the matrix and subsetting by the row name would be preferred.

Comment: `x[c(1:2, match(c("c", "e"), row.names(x))),]`